# How I can put a key in my folder with java

Tags: java, android, directory

I need to put a key in my folder because I need to do my folder more safe. I want only my app can access to that folder.

I use external storage to save my data.  Exists something to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is not possible.

If you want to prevent (most) other apps from accessing the data, put it on [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), not [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html).

Comment: Yes but if I use That, my storage limit will be small and I need a big storage.
Maybe if Do you know something to encrypt image , video or audio. Maybe With That I can solve my problem .
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Renata: Since Android 3.0, on the vast majority of devices, internal and external storage are the same size, because they are on the same partition.

Comment: But I understand the external storage can be a SD Card. I'm mistaken?

Comment: @Renata: Generally, that is [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html). External storage is on-board flash on the vast majority of devices.

Comment: ahhhhhhh ok , perfect then. Thank you very much .

Comment: Sorry but I just saw I can't save pictures or videos with internal storage. Do you know how I can solve that?
I can't because I use my cam for save pictures and videos and internal storage don't let me write in my folder if I come from another application

Comment: @Renata: "I just saw I can't save pictures or videos with internal storage" -- sure you can. "I use my cam for save pictures and videos and internal storage don't let me write in my folder if I come from another application" -- use `FileProvider` to grant the camera app the ability to save photos and videos in your internal storage: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/FileProvider